# Change of path planners

Tags: ros, navfn, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I'm new to ROS, and I'm having trouble changing the default path planner to some other on my project. The project currently uses the `navfn` planner, but I was looking to use `DWA planner` (or other you may suggest). How I'll be able to change that?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/288944/change-of-path-planners/) by [mrphaell](https://answers.ros.org/users/33693/mrphaell/) on ROS Answers with karma: 5 on 2018-04-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Note that `navfn` is a global planner, i.e. it computes that path from a start point to an end point, whereas `dwa_local_planner` is a local planner (as the name suggests) , which is used to avoid obstacles while following a pre-planned (from the global planner) path.

Thus, you cannot substitute one with the other.

Alternatives would be (amongst others):

- for `navfn`: [`global_planner`](http://wiki.ros.org/global_planner?distro=lunar)
- for `dwa_local_planner`: [TrajectoryPlannerROS](http://wiki.ros.org/base_local_planner?distro=lunar#TrajectoryPlannerROS), [`teb_local_planner`](http://wiki.ros.org/teb_local_planner) and others.

You can change them by replacing the respective `base_global_planner` and `base_local_planner` [parameters of `move_base`](http://wiki.ros.org/move_base#Parameters) to the respective planner plugin name.

---

**Edit**

About what plan are you talking now? Global or local?

Anyways, the answer is the same. Choose your appropriate planner algorithm and implement that as the respective LocalPlanner/GlobalPlanner plugin to `move_base`. There is a tutorial about [how to do this for a global planner](http://wiki.ros.org/navigation/Tutorials/Writing%20A%20Global%20Path%20Planner%20As%20Plugin%20in%20ROS) on the wiki.
You can also have a look on other planners how they are implemented.

---

Originally posted by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) with karma: 12390 on 2018-04-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mrphaell](https://answers.ros.org/users/33693/mrphaell/) on 2018-04-18**:
I'm sorry, when I was writing the question I forgot to mention that. I'm using the setup of `navfn` and `TrajectoryPlannerROS`. I wanted to use some kind of genetic algorithm to make the path plan, but I'm having trouble with that, so I thought about changing the current one to any other setup.

**Comment by [mrphaell](https://answers.ros.org/users/33693/mrphaell/) on 2018-04-18**:
Could you by any chance give me a hint of how I could make use of a ga to create the plan?

**Comment by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) on 2018-04-19**:
see edit above